# Drupal Views slide

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal-7

I have this design:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6spc.jpg

E.G. Click "Structure" header, open contents and come img.

Created content type and installed Views. Seperate image, header, content fields via block.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhgmz.png

Like our design but site now static. I want dynamic structure but i don't know. Well, how can i do it?

Comment: please explain a little better what you want to achieve. Do you want a slideshow for the images, or do you want to click on the Structure and dynamicaly view the structure content type titles?

Comment: @ThanosK. i want click on the Structure and dynamicaly view the structre content type files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Views Slideshow module: http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow